# How to hide right caret on dropdown menu liferay 6.2

Tags: css, liferay, liferay-velocity

I have a created a second level submenu on my navbar on Liferay 6.2
I have tried to hide the right arrow caret that is shown always on dropdown menu, when it has a child. You can see it here:

https://s10.postimg.org/67vbfzu7d/caret.jpg

```
<nav class="$nav_css_class navbar site-navigation"  id="navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="collapse nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav sf-menu" >
        #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)
            #set($nav_li_css_class = "")
            #if ($nav_item.isSelected())
                #set($nav_li_css_class = $nav_li_css_class+" selected")
            #end
            #if ($nav_item.hasChildren())
                #set($nav_li_css_class = $nav_li_css_class+" dropdown")
            #end          
            <li class="$nav_li_css_class">
                    #if ($nav_item.hasChildren())
                        <a href="$nav_item.getURL()" $nav_item.getTarget()   data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="100" data-close-others="false">
                            <p>$nav_item.icon() $nav_item.getName()</p>               

                        </a>
                    #else
                         <a href="$nav_item.getURL()" $nav_item.getTarget()>
                            <p>$nav_item.icon() $nav_item.getName()</p>               
                        </a>
                       #end
                #if ($nav_item.hasChildren())
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        #foreach ($nav_child in $nav_item.getChildren())
                            #set($nav_li_css_class = "")
                            #if ($nav_child.isSelected())
                                #set($nav_li_css_class = " selected")
                            #end
                            #if ($nav_child.hasChildren())
                                #set($nav_li_css_class = " dropdown-submenu")
                            #end
                            <li class="$nav_li_css_class">
                                #if ($nav_child.hasChildren())
                                    <a href="$nav_child.getURL()" $nav_child.getTarget()   data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="100" data-close-others="false">
                                        <span>$nav_child.icon() $nav_child.getName()</span>                                                 
                                    </a>
                                #else
                                     <a href="$nav_child.getURL()" $nav_item.getTarget()>
                                        <span>$nav_child.icon() $nav_child.getName()</span>               
                                    </a>
                                   #end
                               #if ($nav_child.hasChildren())
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        #foreach ($nav_child_child in $nav_child.getChildren())
                                               #if ($nav_child_child.isSelected())
                                                <li class="selected">
                                            #else
                                                <li>
                                            #end
                                                <a href="$nav_child_child.getURL()" $nav_child_child.getTarget()>
                                                 <p style="word-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre-line; text-align:left; display:block; ">$nav_child_child.getName()</p>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        #end   
                                   </ul>
                                #end                           
                           </li>
                        #end
                    </ul>
                #end
            </li>
        #end
       </div>
       </div>
</ul>
</nav>

<script>
    Liferay.Data.NAV_LIST_SELECTOR = '.navbar-inner .nav-collapse > ul';
</script>
```

This is a requirement from the company. they want to hide the caret. I have been looking everywhere on my code, but cannot find the way to hide it. I have opened the navigation css and scss styles to try to hide it but can't find the solution. the ugly part is that the caret is not detected in firefox or chrome *element inspector* so, can't find a route.

Comment: Sorry, part of my question was deleted. I was saying... This is a requirement from the company. they want to hide the caret. I have been looking everywhere on my code, but cannot find the way to hide it. I have opened the navigation css and scss styles to try to hide it but can't find the solution. the ugly part is that the caret is not detected in firefox or chrome "element inspector" so, can't find a route.

Comment: your website link?

Comment: @fashbio You can at any time edit your question, as I did for you now.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site